# Why does ram give me these problems?

Tags: memory

I have a problem, having purchased 2x4 gb ram of the 2666 mhz vengeance corsair (CMK8GX4M2A2666C16), when I go to insert the two rams together in the asus prime 320m-k motherboard, the PC restart continuously, while inserting  a single  ram(4gb) the pc is fine. The error I can't tell you which one it is because nothing appears to me, the pc gives me the screen to choose whether to enter the bios, and then it starts up again.

Comment: You will have to describe your problem in more detail.  You should indicated what error you have received.  You should clarity what you mean exactly by "bank ram".  Please edit your question instead of submitting a temporary comment.

Comment: I'm sorry it's the first time I've done these things, and I'm desperate.

Comment: the discussion you sent me, where he talks about possible problems, didn't help me understand my problem because in theory the rams are compatible, but in this case I didn't understand how I should solve, by buying others?

Comment: Have you checked the [memory compatibility list](https://www.asus.com/pl/Motherboards/PRIME-A320M-K/HelpDesk_QVL/)? What CPU do you have? Are you using the [latest BIOS](https://www.asus.com/pl/Motherboards/PRIME-A320M-K/HelpDesk_BIOS/) (memory compatibility was improved in v. 0402)

Comment: i have a amd athlon 200GE, and my ram inserted at the moment in the list of compatible memories are not there, but I'm still using the pc.

Comment: The memory compatibility list contains modules that were confirmed to work. They can't test every module model in existence of course, so modules that aren't listed may work too. If your new module was listed, we could assume it's rather not an incompatibility issue, unfortunately it's not listed. Please check the BIOS version and upgrade to the latest one if you're not using it yet.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure both sticks are good by inserting just one and testing the pc, then the other.  Assuming both pass, go into your bios and set the memory frequency to it's lowest setting (realistically 2133 for DDR4), then reinstall both sticks and see if it works.  Alternatively you can test each stick individually using something like memtest86.  It seems the memory you chose is compatible with you mobo; make certain it is with your processor also.